# Using an SVG icon for an Admin menu bar item

Tags: admin-bar

I'm trying to add a menu item to the admin top bar that has an icon. I'm adding the menu item using the following code:

```
$iconSVG = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12,16A2,2 0 0,1 14,18A2,2 0 0,1 12,20A2,2 0 0,1 10,18A2,2 0 0,1 12,16M12,10A2,2 0 0,1 14,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,14A2,2 0 0,1 10,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,10M12,4A2,2 0 0,1 14,6A2,2 0 0,1 12,8A2,2 0 0,1 10,6A2,2 0 0,1 12,4Z" /></svg>';

$wp_admin_bar->add_node(array(
        'id'    => 'test',
        'title' => 'Test',
        'href'  => 'https://example.com',
        'menu_icon'    => 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' . base64_encode($iconSVG)
));
```

Based on the materials I've seen it seems as if this should work, but my menu item has no icon, just the title. So my questions are:

1. Should this be working?
2. What does/should it actually do? How should setting the 'menu_icon' value affect the HTML output?